# Debugging an Execution Exception Error Based on a Function Within Playframework

Tags: scala, playframework

Today I did couple of updates on the front-end side of things, and then I did get the execution exception error, while running the app, that points to the written code within the `target folder`.

Error:

```
Execution exception
[IllegalStateException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException]
```

Pinter to the error on line 31 (`/target/scala2.11/routes/main/controllers/ReverseRoutes.scala:31`):

```
28 // @LINE:65
29 def versioned(file:Asset): Call = {
30   implicit val _rrc = new ReverseRouteContext(Map(("path", "/public")))
31   Call("GET", _prefix + { _defaultPrefix } + "vassets/" + implicitly[PathBindable[Asset]].unbind("file", file))
32 }
```

Where should I look for this error, as obviously I did not wrote the code within the `target` folder.

**Note 1**: Commented whatever I did after I did get the error, and I do still get the error.

**Note 2**: I did `clean compile` with no error, however when I try to run it through the browser I do get the error.

Answer (score 0):

this error is strictly connected with template and using controllers call (your methods from controllers)

you have to localize on your template which controller method calls this error

for instance I had a problem with nullpointerexception and I found a problem. I had below controller:

```
@controllers.MyController.myMethod(object.getValue)
```

and it turns out that in db getValue had null and play reported it as a problem. he somehow detect that this value is null

Strange for me but maybe it will help